# How to use escape sequences in strings contained in resource files

Tags: c#, string, escaping, resource-files

I have a string that I get from my resources a .resx file

in my resx file I have my key and my string which is:

> Hello\r\n We're just you setting up

now when I pull this string out and bind it to a label in my view I see that exact string where as if I simply set the string to equal that (bypassing the resource file) I get the expected new line behavior

I was wondering if there is a way to keep the behavior of the escape sequence when getting the string from my resource file?

Comment: You're getting confused between text encodings which convert between binary and text, and the escape sequences present in C#. This has nothing to do with UTF-16... you're really just asking about escape sequences in resource files.

Comment: (I don't know of any way of using escape sequences in resx files, I'm afraid.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using char(13) + char(10) in them. In the resources window, you can do this with Shift+Enter.